# What does "До тебя как до осла не доходит" mean?

Tags: перевод, идиомы

The Google and Yandex English translations don't make sense to me.

Comment: It's means "you are an idiot " (or slowpoke)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All together it means *"You idiot don't get it."*

> не доходит

means that person doesn't get it. Literally it means *"doesn't reach"*, probably originating from "idea not reaching one's mind". **This is used often.** My personal impression is that nowadays it's not so frequent as in 1990s. It can be both neutral and rude, depending on the tone and way of saying: one can say angrily *"ну чё, до тебя не доходит что ли?!"*, or politely wonder: *"не дошло?"*.

A joke based on this is: *An animal in the zoo complains: oh God, during the day, the monkey tells jokes, and then the giraffe laughs all the night.*

> как до осла

*like a donkey*. Calling one a donkey is equal to calling one an idiot. I can't recall what animal has a similar role in English. It's very rude.

Comment: Thank you. Is this commonly said between Russians? Is it said as a joke, or is it said seriously?

Comment: It is said seriously and it's rude, there are other ways to say this jokingly. And it's used very rarely.

Comment: @rickhg12hs What you mean by "commonly"? Is "dumb idiot" a common phrase in English?

Comment: @Matt For example, a friend might call another friend an idiot, half jokingly, for spilling a drink. Other words, or the seriousness would be heightened for someone who drives their car into a river thinking that it will float and be maneuverable.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Yeah, I mean it's just the same thing in Russian. Not really polite, yet it depends.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I updated the answer to describe usage.

Answer (score 3):

It's rather a nonce expression than a popular one (I even failed to google it). However, it is understandable: the same as to call somebody a donkey (1 - stubborn, 2- silly animal). A popular expression to say that *somebody is slow minded*: "**до него доходит как до жирафа**". This is a hint that due to its long neck it takes a while for a jiraffe to receive the sound of words, same as it takes some time for that person to understand something.